# Is there any way to recover a lost database password?

Tags: monetdb

We have a monetdb database which we can no longer get in to. The password we have recorded and also stored in the user's SQL client no longer works. Is there any way to bypass this and recover the password or the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your password by executing following MAL commands in mserver prompt:

```
oldp:=clients.getPasswordHash("username");
newp:=clients.backendsum("newpassword");
clients.changePassword(oldp, newp);
```